# I Can't Target .Net Framework in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-4.8

When I create a Project in Visual Studio, I can't choose .net framework as my target framework, I only have the choice between .net core 3 and .net 5, I have already downloaded and installed .net framework 4.8 Developer Pack but nothing changed.

Comment: You need to pay attention to the project types - some are e.g. "Console App" (which is .NET **Core** - 3.1 or 5.0), while another might be called "Console App (.NET Framework)" which is for the various versions of the full, classic .NET framework. If you picked the .NET Core template - then yes, you cannot target the "classic" .NET Framework - just create the **correct** project type from the correct template and you should be fine

Comment: Try opening your csproj file and change the TargetFramework property to "net48".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pay attention to the template you create your project with - some are e.g. "Console App" (which is for .NET **Core** - 3.1 or 5.0), while another might be called "Console App (.NET Framework)" which is for the various versions of the full, classic .NET framework:

[image]

If you picked the .NET Core template - then yes, you cannot target the "classic" .NET Framework - just create the correct project type from the correct template and you should be fine

Comment: any way to remove this confusing core template?